# PHP - Different value shown when accessing id attribute

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an issue accessing an attribute from my Laravel app.

A simple query to fetch user is this:

```
$login = Users::select('user_id' ,'email', 'password')->where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();
```

I've did `dd($login)` and it shows the attributes:

[image]
But accessing it's `user_id` shows different (`dd($login->user_id)`):

[image]

accessing email `(dd($login->email))` is ok though.

table struct:

[image]

Comment: Does that ID exist in your users table?

Comment: No..I'm wondering..Because I've placed protected $casts = [ 'user_id' => 'double']; on the Users model just now, and it shows 17000040899.0 ...though there's .0 at the end..I'm wondering if it's a type issue on the ID(using bigint atm)?

Comment: Can you append structure of table? And what database type do you use?

Comment: Hi..I appended it above.

Answer (score 1):

Well..looks like a limit to my php.. I'm using 32-bit php where the max integer value is 2147483647..or switch to string.